# Update a single CommonJS module without having to touch every single module it is required in

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, commonjs

This may be a bit complicated to follow but I'll do my best. I have a series of API modules that I'm using with Browserify, and some of them call other modules as well. They are pretty much interwoven, which is going to make updates difficult.

For example, let's say I have five modules: A, B, C, D, and E. A is required by B and C, and B is required by C, D, and E. If I need to make some updates to A that are breaking changes, I could version it, but then I need to update the require statements in B and C. And since B is now using a different version of A, I need to version B as well, which means changing the require statements in C, D, and E. So a single change in one module means I have to reversion everything else.

I should note that the main reason for this is that I have to keep old versions around. These are small microsites, and one site might get built with A - E and the next might get built with A' - E', but I still need to be able to build both independently. Even though the change to A' may not have an effect on the API it exposes, I have no desire to have to go back and re-test every single project ever built with each single file modification.

I thought about having a separate per-project file that could be required in and it then requires all of the versioned modules for that project, but that's a circular dependency.

If it matters, I'm using Gulp and Browserify to build the final JS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that would do the trick: [aliasify](https://github.com/benbria/aliasify)

I changed my require statements to `require('Api/ModuleA')` and then in the aliasify config I map `Api/ModuleA` to `./libs/Api/ModuleA-1.0` and it picks up the version I want every time it requires Module A.

Answer (score 0):

I used a mechanism similar to Java classpaths. I created a custom module resolver and used separate module roots for separate projects. Ther was also a folder for common files. The module resolver first searced for the module in the project's folder, and if it wasn't found searched for it in the common folder. This way you can provide a specialized implementation of module A for a specific project. Not sure if its suitable in your case. It is something like aliasify with the difference of the config being backed by filesystem folders instead of config files.

`A` is a module with only a few dependencies, and is referenced by many modules. They usually call that kind of module "mature". These mature modules should be well-tested, and the public interface should not change often, as every dependant module would need to be updated. So you might try to make the changes without breaking the api, possibly creating a new module with versioned name, and a wrapper of the module which provides the old api using the new module. New components could use the new module, old components are not affected.

They use multiple numbers to version a software for a reason. In the simplest case there are two numbers: major and minor versions. Minor version can change with every release, major version increases when the public api changes. All components that depend on this one only need to be updated when major versions change. (of course sometimes there are bugs in the implementation of a minor version that breaks some depending components, but thats not the usual case). If you change the public api of `A`, you need to change `B` and `C` too, but not the others.`A` would have a major version change, B and C would have a minor. The rest stays the same. This needs a more complicated module resolver which can resolve the latest modules by their major version. But thats what npm does anyway.

Comment: I thought about using fallbacks, but different versions aren't *necessarily* deprecating an older one. Same reason that it isn't always an API change. For instance, a Logger might need to add an additional logging source for some projects, or a Data module might need to organize differently. The external API isn't changing, and one isn't "newer" or "better" in the versioning sense, it is just different.

Comment: I think a logging module shouldn't depend on its sources nor its targets. It could provide a configurable interface, and the main entry of the application (which is different for every project) can provide the list of logging sources or targets.